# primeng display of grid with alignment issue between p-col-1 and p-col-2

Tags: alignment, primeng

[image]If all p-col-1, all aligned in one row. If all p-col-2, all aligned in one row.
If mixed, there is alignment issue between p-col-2 and p-col-1.

Comment: Show some screenshots perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

at parent level, apply center style.

```
 <div class="p-grid" style="align-items: center ">
```